# How to create file->node relations use relations modules?

Tags: views

I have a little issue that How to create file->node relations use relations modules?

In my case:
   I need to create music(mp3) and album relations. After i check some information and said that music(mp3) and album is file->node relations.

But, i don't know that how to do this relations.

when i create a relation type, which bundles need to selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resolved]
1. Create relation between Node and file
2. Create a view for relation and only view out all related file
3. setting view to relation select values